# Do the letters ol in a substance only indicate that the substance is an alcohol if they came at the end of the name of a substance?

Tags: nomenclature, alcohols

Do the letters ol if they are together only indicate the substance is an alcohol if they come together at the end of the name of a substance? for example,is glycerol an alcohol because the letters o and l come together at the end of its name and olives and olive oil are not alcohols because the letters o and l do not come together at the end of any words in their names?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the **ending** *ol* in a name is a good hint that the compound contains an $\ce{OH}$ group.

However, beware of trivial names:

- [$\alpha$-tocopherol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha-Tocopherol) is not an aliphatic alcohol, but a substituted phenol
- [mannitol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mannitol) does not contain one $\ce{OH}$ group, but six of them

It's getting even more confusing if you consider other languages, such as German. *Benzol* is the German name of *benzene*, which has no $\ce{OH}$ group at all. The same is true for *styrol*, the German word for *styrene* ;-)

Comment: Gotcha but one thing I do want to get clarified-if the letters o and l are together at any spot in the name of a substance other than at the end of a word in that name,that does not mean that the substance is an alcohol,right (to use my previous examples,that means olives and olive oil are definitely not alcohols,right?)

Comment: Right :) Bisab**ol**en is not an alcohol, gerani**ol** and farnes**ol** are.